# Starting create-react-app / react-scripts server from within docker container 'fails' with error code 0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, create-react-app

My screen output is:

```
frontend    | 
frontend    | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.16.2/
frontend    | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
frontend    | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
frontend    | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
frontend    | Starting the development server...
frontend    | 
frontend exited with code 0
```

That's all I get. When I replace last line in Dockerfile `CMD ["npm", "start"]` with `ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]`, start, bash into it and execute `npm start` manually, everything works as expected. Any directions?

Comment: If you use `react-scripts` version `3.4.1`, it's still an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688).

Comment: Thanks for the directions, I ended up 
adding
```environment:
    - CI=true
```
to my dev docker-compose as described in discussion behind your link. Using 3.4.1